# c# ComboBox with Class Assigned - Need to Retrieve Multiple Values

Tags: c#, combobox

I have assigned a class to a `ComboBox`. The `ComboBox` pick list appears properly, but when the user chooses a value, I want the ability to retrieve any of the 3 values (`sDirectoryAlias`, `sDirectory`, or `bFileName`). Here is my code:

```
public class ComboBoxItem_DirectoryToLoad
{
    public string sDirectoryAlias { get; set; }
    public string sDirectory { get; set; }
    public bool bFileName { get; set; }
}

private void BuildDirectoryComboBox()
{
    var dataSource = new List<ComboBoxItem_DirectoryToLoad>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in cls_global_variables.dictDirectoriesToLoad)
    {
        string[] sTemp = pair.Value.Split('|');           
        dataSource.Add(new ComboBoxItem_DirectoryToLoad() { sDirectoryAlias = sTemp[0], sDirectory = sTemp[1], bFileName = Convert.ToBoolean(sTemp[2]) });
    }

    this.cb_directories_to_load.DataSource = dataSource;
    this.cb_directories_to_load.DisplayMember = "sDirectoryAlias";
}

private void cb_directories_to_load_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = this.cb_directories_to_load.SelectedItem["sDirectory"];
}
```

So the part that isn't working here is this:

```
string s = this.cb_directories_to_load.SelectedItem["sDirectory"];
```

On `SelectedIndexChanged`, I want to be able to assign `s` to any of the 3 class properties.

Comment: Have you tried `string s = ((ComboBoxItem_DirectoryToLoad)this.cb_directories_to_load.SelectedItem).sDirectory`?

Comment: Yes.  That didn't work.  I get all sorts of compilation errors

Comment: Yes.  It is a winforms app.

Comment: Well the code i posted in the comment above works fine for me (VS2012 .NET4.5)

Comment: My apologies....that did work.  Somehow the event on my ComboBox was not properly linked.  Thanks for your help!!!!